# Any way to access mouse Raw Input from WPF?

Tags: wpf, mouse, slimdx, raw-input

I'm currently using a global mouse hook to make an app appear if it the mouse cursor reaches the corner of the screen. I just read about the existence of Raw Input and from what I understand, this is a more robust method as a slowdown in my hook will not impact the overall system.

**Problem is I can't find any examples anywhere about using Raw Input in WPF.**

Closest I got was SlimDX with the following code:

```
  Device.RegisterDevice(UsagePage.Generic, UsageId.Mouse, 
                        DeviceFlags.None);

  Device.MouseInput += new EventHandler<MouseInputEventArgs>(mouse_MouseInput);
```

But that does not seem to work in WPF, only winforms.

Comment: Essentially you need to use DllImport to access the GetRawInputData function and process WM_INPUT messages.  Here is a link to a CodeProject that gives a good base:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17123/Using-Raw-Input-from-C-to-handle-multiple-keyboard.  This code project was created to allow for multiple keyboards, but if you pay close attention, you'll see they also do support the mouse to some degree.  It's not a complete answer, but it's a good start.

Comment: Thanks Josh. With some work, I've managed to get the events in a WPF app, only to find out the coordinates are always relative. Don't think I can make this work for my usage. even if I add the deltas up, they will diverge from reality because I still get deltas when the cursor hits a screen edge!

Answer (score 0):

Those `DeviceFlags.None` need to be `InputSink` to capture input in the background. SharpDX flags there are actually a wrapper for the [RAWINPUTDEVICEFLAGS](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/RawInputDeviceFlags.html) (`InputSink = 0x00000100`).

In WPF, you want to 1) override `OnSourceInitialized` and 2) hook `WndProc` there. While the window pointer is available you need to define the RAWINPUTDEVICE's you want to watch, flag `InputSink`.

It will look something like

```
protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
    HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
    source.AddHook(WndProc);

    var win = source.Handle;

    RAWINPUTDEVICE[] rid = new RAWINPUTDEVICE[2];

    rid[0].UsagePage = (HIDUsagePage)0x01;
    rid[0].Usage = (HIDUsage)0x05;                 // adds game pad
    rid[0].Flags = RawInputDeviceFlags.InputSink;  // accept input in background
    rid[0].WindowHandle = win;

    rid[1].UsagePage = (HIDUsagePage)0x01;
    rid[1].Usage = (HIDUsage)0x04;                 // adds joystick
    rid[1].Flags = RawInputDeviceFlags.InputSink;  // accept input in background
    rid[1].WindowHandle = win;

    if (RegisterRawInputDevices(rid, (uint)rid.Length, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(rid[0])) == false)
    {
        var err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (err > 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception($"GetLastWin32Error: {err}");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Win32Exception("RegisterRawInputDevices failed with error code 0. Parameter count mis-match?");
        }
    }
}

private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_INPUT:
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Received WndProc.WM_INPUT");
                DoTheThing(lParam);
            }
            break;
    }
    return hwnd;
}
```